# CakePHP: Find "Groups" where the "Members" of that group are not the current authorized user

Tags: php, cakephp, models

I have a Groups model and a Users model.

Groups have and belong to many users.
Users have and belong to many groups.

I'm trying to create a result set of groups where the group users do not include the id of the currently logged in user. I've tried to use a conditional in the "contain" parameter and I've tried to do it using an inner join but the results always come up with groups that the user currently belongs to.

Short of doing my own custom MySQL query, I was wondering if there was a way I could do it using the CakePHP models exclusively.

Examples of what I have tried:

```
$otherMatches = $this->Group->find('all', array('joins' => array(array('table' => 'cake_users_groups', 'alias' => 'GroupsUsers', 'type' => 'inner', 'conditions' => array('GroupsUsers.group_id !=' => $groupId, 'GroupsUsers.user_id !=' => $this->Auth->user('id')))), 'limit' => 10, 'order' => array('rand()')));
```

and

```
$otherMatches = $this->Group->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'User' => array(
            'UsersGroup' => array(
                'conditions' =>  array('UsersGroup.user_id !=' => $this->Auth->user('id));
            )
        )
    )
), 'limit' => 10, 'order' => array('rand()')));
```

Could anyone give me any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need only the groups, or groups and users? Are you restricted to just 1 query?

Comment: Only the groups will do fine. If it is possible to get the User info with the Group then that would be good, but not necessary. Not necessarily restricted to one query, but would like to keep the code to as minimum as possible.

Comment: Seems that a subquery should be the way to go. As there are no subqueries in Cake 2.x, probably the fastest and less 'headache-able' answer will be to do 2 queries

Comment: Ok thanks, Eagle. That gives me a starting point.

Comment: `'conditions' =>  array('UsersGroup.user_id !=' => $this->Auth->user('id));` should work in my opinion. Is it because of the lack of a single quote after `$this->Auth->user('id` or when trying, did you have it written correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jimmy. Sorry, it was correct in my code. I didn't get any PHP errors and there was a resultset, but it included groups that the currently authorised user was a member of. I eventually solved the problem by doing a sub query as per Eagle's suggestion. I'll post the result below.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using a sub query:

```
$conditionsSubQuery['`UsersGroup`.`user_id`'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

    $db = $this->UsersGroup->getDataSource();
    $subQuery = $db->buildStatement(
            array(
                'fields'     => array('`UsersGroup`.`group_id`'),
                'table'      => $db->fullTableName($this->UsersGroup),
                'alias'      => 'UsersGroup',
                'limit'      => null,
                'offset'     => null,
                'joins'      => array(),
                'conditions' => $conditionsSubQuery,
                'order'      => null,
                'group'      => null
            ),
            $this->UsersGroup
        );
        $subQuery = ' `Group`.`id` NOT IN (' . $subQuery . ') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ';
        $subQueryExpression = $db->expression($subQuery);

        $conditions[] = $subQueryExpression;

        $otherMatches = $this->Group->find('all', compact('conditions'));
```